# drupal how to refresh the page when the content is created in the popups

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules, drupal-panels

i have designed a panel where i have to used 
to popup links and automodal class for creation of content....

```
<a href ="/testviewprintpdf/<?php echo $object; ?> " class ="popups-form-noreload">view objects</a>
```

now after saving the content , and closing the popup  the panel page is to be refreshed

how it is done.....
it sounds simple but 
i m newbie to drupal

Comment: Indent your code with 4 spaces so that it displays as code instead of being rendered.

Comment: Is this a Drupal or a Javascript issue?

Answer (score 0):

From your class name, it would seem you are using the popups module?  If that is true, and you want the parent where the popup is launched from to refresh when the popup is closed, you want the class to be "popups-form-reload"

```
<a href ="/testviewprintpdf/<?php echo $object; ?> " class ="class="popups-form-reload"">view objects</a>
```

Seems like you have a link on a page that launches the popup when clicked.  You can use the Drupal [l syntax](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/l/6), l for link

```
l("view objects", 'testviewprintpdf', array('attributes'=>array
    (array('class' => 'popups-form-reload'))))
```

Comment: what if when i use class ='automodal' instead of class="popups-form-reload"
because in the class ="popups-form-reload" the date field is not working .....


any idead to do that...

Comment: what do you mean when you say the "date field is not working"?  I would suggest that you debug a bit and separate out your issues.  Are the date field issues only occurring when you use the popup or do the date field issues occur when you are not using the popup as well?

Comment: actually date field is a popup up calendar....
i don think that we can open a popup in popup ......